# Dynamically create dataframe

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create a dataframe with columns names given by user.
Like I have some `textInputs(name1, name2, etc)` and `textInputs(value1, value2, etc)`.
Now I want to create dataframe with entries in `name1`, `name2` as column names and corresponding entries in `value1`, `value2` as dataframe entries.

How can I do this

Comment: use `?setNames`

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: `reactive(setNames(c(req(input$value1),req(input$value2)), c(req(input$name1),req(input$name2)))`?